# Cannot resolve "setVolumeControlStream" in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-audiomanager, sinch

I am trying to use setVolumeControlStream inside a Fragment used in a ViewPager. When building, Gradle throws

```
error: cannot find symbol method setVolumeControlStream(int)
```

Is there any way to call the following in a Fragment?

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
getActivity().setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

Comment: Can you please give code where the problem occuring??